# Speed of light dependent on source velocity in other medium

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, refraction

Does speed of light depends upon the velocity of source in a medium (like water) other than space? if yes, does the speed gets added up when the light source moves in direction of light?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the speed of medium affect the path of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113321/)

Answer (score 0):

No, the velocity of the source does not affect the speed of light in any medium.  The velocity of the *medium*, except when the medium is a vacuum, does affect the velocity of light in the medium.

Comment: If the source is moving, the medium is relatively moving... So shouldn't the source velocity affect its speed

Comment: If the speed of light of a given frequency is measured *inside the medium*, it is dependent on the properties of the medium and nothing else.